# Typescript - How to create three state toggle button that changes color and text when clicked

Tags: typescript, widget, figma

I was coding using typescript to develop a button that changes three states ie. changes color and text on loop when clicked. I have attached the interaction below.

Can someone help with the code for the interaction below? :D

Click to view interaction gif

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of different state (label and style) and loop over it when you click on the button. When you reach the last index of your array you reset the index at the desire position.

Here is a working example: [codepen example](https://codepen.io/maximedaraize/pen/PoeYXLq)

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#multiStateBtn');
let index = 1;
 
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(index > 2) {
    index = 0;
  }
  btn.innerHTML = btnState[index].label;
  btn.style.backgroundColor = btnState[index].color;
  index++;
})

const btnState = [
  {
    label: 'completed',
    color: 'green'
  },
  {
    label: 'under review',
    color: 'yellow'
  },
  {
    label: 'in progress',
    color: 'red'
  }
]
```

```css
#multiStateBtn {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="multiStateBtn">completed</button>
```